# How to make a church bell

Tags: design

I'm planning a scene that includes a church bell. It's will need to fit into roughly 10X10X6 space.  It doesn't need to actually make any sound but the ability to swing a bit would be nice.
Here's the [image from the scene](https://pm1.narvii.com/6627/5c120e60b762d99980836fbb809dbca655406a7b_hq.jpg)

I figure I can use a bar, some clips and some stoplights to make the swinging part. Can anyone recomend some parts for the bell itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the bell in the Lego kit for Big Ben (#10253). Building instructions are [here](https://www.lego.com/en-sg/service/buildinginstructions/search?initialsearch=10253#?text=10253) (Step 276).

The bell itself is made from several round plates and parabolic reflector dishes. It's not hollow, but it could certainly be made to swing.